# Error while redirecting callback to modal dialog window

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a main search page with a find and enquire button.

When I click the enquire button. I open a modaldialog window and allow user to enter his name and I'd and hit submit. I transfer the call to a servlet and query is db. If the response takes longer than 30 sec. I forward the request back to the modal page and resubmit the form.

When I forward the request back to the modal window to resubmit I get a script error. The script error occurs before the form.Submit.  Am I doing something wrong in forwarding the request. Back.

Edited:

File1.jsp: I call File2.jsp on a button click

```
returnVal= showModalDialog ( "File2.jsp?Name=Jack" , "" , "dialogWidth:650px;dialogHeight:400px" );
```

In File2.jsp:

```
<form name="Refresh" action="<%=contextPath%>/Someservlet" id="Refreshing"  method="post" target="result">
```

I have a name field here with a button to submit
set a hidden param request_old ='N'

```
</form>
```

On submitting the button:
In Somservlet.java

I get the parameter
Call a threadpool executor
if request_old ='N' I execute the TPE
else I just wait for response
Wait for 10 sec for response from db

If response did not come back: I set a param

```
request_old ='Y'
```

and send it back to the calling

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("File2.jsp?Name=Jack").forward ( request, response );
```

So this should resturn the call back to File2.jsp

But somewhere before File2.jsp's form.submit--> I get a script error Object not found

Error:
Object expected
under url it shows my context path with the servlet name.

What confuses me is whether the showmodal dialog is not able to re-submit, or is there an issue in the servlet calling the jsp?

I have been trying to figure this one for 3 days now. any help appreciated.

Web.xml mapping is correct
re-direction happens with a weird script error. I am executing this in IE (using js and servlet)

Comment: Please provide the code you're using and the specific error message so we can better solve your problem.

Comment: eddited as requested with more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RE-wrote the files from scratch to make it works. Issues with one of the supporting js files was the cause.